# How to add an entity content programmatically in drupal

Tags: entity, backend, drupal-8

Good night: I used to create node programmatically with a code similar to:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$nodeObj = Node::create([
  'type' => 'article',
  'title' => 'Programatically created Article',
  'body' => "CodeExpertz is contains best Blogs.",
  'field_date' => '2017-10-24',
  'field_category' => 'Study',
  'uid' => 1,
]);

$nodeObj->save(); // Saving the Node object.
$nid = $nodeObj->id(); // Get Nid from the node  object.
Print "Node Id is " . $nid;
```

Now I want to create entities content (no nodes) but I can't find something about this. I tried to adapt the next snippet:

```
$term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
          'vid' => 'test_vocabulary',
          'name' => 'My tag',
    ]);
$term->save();
```

to this (vehicle is my entity):

```
$newvehicle = \Drupal\vehicle\Entity\Vehicle::create([
          'title' => 'Ferrari'
    ]);
$newvehicle->save();
```

The result is the white page of death.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with this code

```
use Drupal\customModule\Entity\entityCustom;

$entityCustom = entityCustom::create([
    'type' => 'custom_entity',
    'uid' => 1,
    'status' => TRUE,
    'promote' => 0,
    'created' => time(),
    'langcode' => 'en',
    'name' => 'NAME',
  ]);
  $entityCustom->save();
```